# Layer location/shapefiles of QGIS

Tags: qgis

On QGIS 3.10, after I saved and close my file, and then reopen it.

The layers are unidentified, so I browse for the file location (shapefiles).

When I press on browse, the folders that appear is not the location of the shapefiles.

In other words, where does QGIS store the shapefiles?

I searched every folder of QGIS in program files, and I saw not of the Python shapefiles.

[image]

Comment: Your shapefiles might be stored in temp location. Try saving one more file in the similar way and note the default location.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS doesn't store shapefile, it only access/load them and QGIS project file doesn't store any data but only reference their location.

Your shapefile should still be in their original folder, if you moved them you need to navigate to their original location to restore the link, if you delete them you need to find a way to get them again....

Comment: No, I did not set a folder where all the shapefiles are stored. There is a default folder in which the shapefiles are saved. This is the folder I am talking about

Comment: If QGIS reference it, then it will reference to that default folder where the Shapefiles are saved. This is what I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

`C:\users\{your username}\documents` is where I found a shapefile that I exported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).